# iterating through float - variable input can change to float

Tags: python, numpy

i am calculating protein capacities (steric mass action model) within several loops (i know, filling up a numpy array can be quite slow and there are faster methods, but it works for now):

```
import numpy as np

a = [10,20,30] # salt concentrations tested
b = [4,5,6] # measured data points
c = 2 # number of components
q = np.empty((c,len(a),len(b)))
for ii,cs in enumerate(a):
    for iii,cp in enumerate(b):          
        for i in range(c):           
            q[i,ii,iii] = cs*cp
```

Basically, q contains the measured data points for each component at each salt concentration and has the shape (number of components,number of salt concentrations,number of measurements). The code works fine. However, if i use only one salt concentration, the line `for ii,cs in enumerate(a):` does not work anymore (float object is not iterable).

I can use `if` statements. But is there a better way ( less confusing code) ?

Answer (score 2):

When you use a single salt concentration, instead of writing

```
a = 2
```

write

```
a = [2]
```

This way you'll keep it as a list and your code will still work.

By the way, you can compute `q` using the following NumPy one-liner:

```
In [39]: np.tile(np.outer(a, b), (c, 1, 1))
Out[39]: 
array([[[ 40,  50,  60],
        [ 80, 100, 120],
        [120, 150, 180]],

       [[ 40,  50,  60],
        [ 80, 100, 120],
        [120, 150, 180]]])
```

Comment: THX for the tip with np.tile. I am using it but did not consider using it this way. Awesome. I knew this can be done better.

Comment: Well, i was a little bit to quick with my enthusiasm. q is actually a more complex function and involves several calls to other functions, including one call to fsolve. Nevertheless, i learned a lot. THX

Comment: @Moritz: The one-liner is equivalent to the code in your question. For something more complicated, feel free to post another question. ;)

Comment: I heard soemthing like: "premature optimization is the root of all evil" For now it is working. But i will.

Comment: @Moritz: Good strategy. That said, if you're doing NumPy, it would be beneficial in the long run to start thinking in terms of vectorised operations (as opposed to explicit loops).